# listen to Keyboard input

Tags: vb6, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a vb 6 program in which the form opens up like a power point slide I created a textbox for getting keyboard inputs like esc, left key, right key, up key or down key just like in MS Powerpoint. However when adding many controls to the form the user might click on any of them and the keycode attached to my textbox control (which I called cmdline) the will not work unless I add another code to the other controls to force focus of the cursor to the cmdline

```
Private Sub cmdline_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
        'Space Key
        If KeyCode = 32 Then
            cmdPlay_Click
        End If

         'Page Up Key
        If KeyCode = 33 Then
            showFirstStanza
        End If

        'Page Down Key
        If KeyCode = 34 Then
            showLastStanza
        End If

        'End Key
        If KeyCode = 35 Then
            showLastStanza
        End If

        'Home Key
        If KeyCode = 36 Then
            showFirstStanza
        End If

        'Left key
        If KeyCode = 37 Then
            SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") - 2)
            lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If

        'Up Key
        If KeyCode = 38 Then
            cmdPrev_Click
        End If

        'Right Arrow
        If KeyCode = 39 Then
            SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") + 2)
            lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If

        'Down Arrow
        If KeyCode = 40 Then
            cmdNext_Click
        End If

        'Key C
        If KeyCode = 67 Then
            fonttypez = fonttypez - 1
            Select Case fonttypez
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                font_type_tosave
            Case Else
                fonttypez = 13
                font_type_tosave
            End Select
                font_type_int
                lblSongText.FontName = SiteSettings("projection_font_type")
        End If

        'Key V
        If KeyCode = 86 Then
            fonttypez = fonttypez + 1
            Select Case fonttypez
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                font_type_tosave
            Case Else
                fonttypez = 13
                font_type_tosave
            End Select
                font_type_int
                lblSongText.FontName = SiteSettings("projection_font_type")
        End If

        'Key X
        If KeyCode = 88 Then
            kala = kala + 1
            Select Case kala
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            Case Else
                kala = 1
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            End Select
                SetProjectionTheme
        End If

        'Key Z
        If KeyCode = 90 Then
            kala = kala - 1
            Select Case kala
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            Case Else
                kala = 1
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            End Select
                SetProjectionTheme
        End If

        'Add Key
        If KeyCode = 107 Then
            SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") + 2)
            lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If

        'Subtract Key
        If KeyCode = 109 Then
            SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") - 2)
            lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Does any one have a code that can help me get keyboard input without having a control attached to it.

By the way using a menu is very cool since the keyboard input will be captured easily no matter which control is focussed. By I dont want to use the menu on this form unless if it can be hidden.

Comment: [KeyPreview Property: MSDN Visual Basic Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235137(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: but I dont see anything near what you referenced

Comment: Also, you might want to consider usage of 'Select Case KeyCode', 'Case 32', 'cmdPlay_Click', 'Case ...', 'End Select'. The way you coded it, *all* the 'If' statements are executed on *each and every* keystroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement what you wanted:

- There is a function that needs to be declared at the top as you will
  see in my code.
- Then write a function to get controls pressed on your
  keyboard.
- You will need a loop or something like a timer with
  the interval of 1000 to use to call your function

Here is the modified code that implements what you wanted

```
 'declare this function at the top of your form:        
       Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
    Public Function getControls()
        'Space Key
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeySpace) <> 0 Then 'code 32
            cmdPlay_Click
        End If     
         'Page Up Key 
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyPageUp) <> 0 Then 'code 33
            showFirstStanza
        End If

        'Page Down Key
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyPageDown) <> 0 Then 'code 34
            showLastStanza
        End If

        'End Key 
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyEnd) <> 0 Then 'code 35
            showLastStanza
        End If

        'Home Key 
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyHome) <> 0 Then 'code 36
            showFirstStanza
        End If

        'Left key
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLeft) <> 0 Then 'code 37
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") - 2)
                lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If

        'Up Key
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyUp) <> 0 Then 'code 38
            cmdPrev_Click
        End If 

        'Right Arrow 
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRight) <> 0 Then 'code 39
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") + 2)
                lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If

        'Down Arrow
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyDown) <> 0 Then 'code 40
            cmdNext_Click
        End If 

        'Key C
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyC) <> 0 Then 'code 67
            fonttypez = fonttypez - 1
            Select Case fonttypez
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                font_type_tosave
            Case Else
                fonttypez = 13
                font_type_tosave
            End Select
                font_type_int
                lblSongText.FontName = SiteSettings("projection_font_type")
        End If 

        'Key V
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyV) <> 0 Then 'code 87
            fonttypez = fonttypez + 1
            Select Case fonttypez
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                font_type_tosave
            Case Else
                fonttypez = 13
                font_type_tosave
            End Select
                font_type_int
                lblSongText.FontName = SiteSettings("projection_font_type")
        End If 

        'Key X
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyX) <> 0 Then 'code 88
            kala = kala + 1
            Select Case kala
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            Case Else
                kala = 1
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            End Select
                SetProjectionTheme
        End If 

        'Key Z
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyZ) <> 0 Then 'code 90
            kala = kala - 1
            Select Case kala
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            Case Else
                kala = 1
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("preffered_theme", kala)
            End Select
                SetProjectionTheme
        End If 

        'Add Key
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyAdd) <> 0 Then 'code 107
                SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") + 2)
                lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If 

        'Subtract Key
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeySubtract) <> 0 Then 'code 109
               SavedThis = SaveSettings("projection_font_size", SiteSettings("projection_font_size") - 2)
                lblSongText.FontSize = SiteSettings("projection_font_size")
        End If 

        'ESCAPE KEY
        If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyEscape) <> 0 Then
            Unload Me
        End If

    End Function

    Private Sub trmListen_Timer()
        Call getControls
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you sir for such a nice answer that works like charm